# Inconsistent cells when calling getAllCellInfo in onCellLocationChanged handler

Tags: java, android

I'm writing an app that needs to be notified when the currently serving cell is changed. So I implemented a PhoneStateListener that listens to cell location changes and is started by the following function:

```
public void start() {
    if (mContext == null) {
        Log.e(AutoWifi.LOGTAG, "Context in PhoneStateListener was null");
        return;
    }

    if (this.mTM != null) {
        this.mTM.listen(this, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CELL_LOCATION);
        Log.v(AutoWifi.LOGTAG, "Registered listener for onCellInfoChanged and onCellLocationChanged");
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

`mTM` is a `TelephonyManager` that is once created in the listeners CTOR. The corresponding callback function looks like:

```
@Override
public void onCellLocationChanged(CellLocation location) {
    Log.v(AutoWifi.LOGTAG, "onCellLocationChanged(CellLocation)");
    super.onCellLocationChanged(location);
    Log.v(AutoWifi.LOGTAG, "oclc:cid=" + ((GsmCellLocation) location).getCid()); // (1) (A)
    this.refreshActiveCell(); // (B)
}
```

Until now everything works fine. The handler gets called everytime a cell change occurs and the location object contains the cell id of the new cell (for GSM/UMTS/LTE networks). But as I do also need the MNC and MCC values of the new serving cell (both are not provided in an `CellLocation` object) I call my own `refreshActiveCell()` function that uses `getAllCellInfo` and `CellInfo.isRegistered` to determine the new serving cell and looks like:

```
public void refreshActiveCell() {
    List<CellInfo> cells = this.mTM.getAllCellInfo();
    this.mActiveCells.clear();
    if (cells != null) {
        for (final CellInfo ccell : cells) {
            if (ccell.isRegistered() == true) {
                this.mActiveCells.add(ccell);
            }
        }
    }

    CellInfo activecell = null;
    if (this.mActiveCells.size() > 0) {
        activecell = this.mActiveCells.get(0);
    }

    String cellidstr = "-/-";

    if (activecell == null) {
        cellidstr = "-/-";
    } else {
        if (activecell instanceof CellInfoGsm) {
            final CellInfoGsm gcell = (CellInfoGsm) activecell;
            cellidstr = Integer.toString(gcell.getCellIdentity().getCid());
        } else if (activecell instanceof CellInfoWcdma) {
            final CellInfoWcdma wcell = (CellInfoWcdma) activecell;
            cellidstr = Integer.toString(wcell.getCellIdentity().getCid());
        } else if (activecell instanceof CellInfoLte) {
            final CellInfoLte lcell = (CellInfoLte) activecell;
            cellidstr = Integer.toString(lcell.getCellIdentity().getCi());
        } else {
            cellidstr = "-/-";
        }
    }
    Log.d(AutoWifi.LOGTAG, "activecell:" + cellidstr); // (2) (C)

    // ...
}
```

And now things get a bit confusing: when a cell changed from UMTS networks to LTE occurs (with a change in MNC values) the cell location passed to the `onCellLocationChanged` callback function contains the correct ci value of the new LTE-cell (output at (1)). But the `activecell` object in `refreshActiveCell` that should also represent the new serving cell (determined by using the `TelephonyManager.getAllCellInfo()` and `CellInfo.isRegistered` function) still represents the old UMTS-cell (output at (2)).
When a cell change from LTE to UMTS is performed same things happen.

I debugged the app and had breakpoints at several lines: when having set breakpoints at (A) or (B) (that are hit and I continued the app) everything works fine and the `activecell` object and the cell location passed to the callback function have the same cell id.
When setting a breakpoint at (C) (that is also hit) the problem described above occurs again.

So my question is: why is the cell id (and with that obviously the currently serving cell) contained in the `CellLocation` object passed to `onCellLocationChanged` different from the one determined by `TelephonyManager.getAllCellInfo()` and `CellInfo.isRegistered()`? Am I not allowed to use `getAllCellInfo` inside the callback function handler? And is there an other way to get the whole `CellInfo` object for the new serving cell (and not just the cell location) inside the `onCellLocationChanged` callback function?

BTW: I am using a Sony smartphone with Android 5.1.1, API-level 22 and Android Studio. So currently the min-SDK is also 22. In the manifest file I set the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```